# Emitting keyboard input using WM_CHAR message?

Tags: c++, c, windows, events, unicode

I'm working on a virtual keyboard for windows. I know i can emit keyboard events by using (for example) `keybd_event()` with the right virtual key code, but this method is totally unpractical, and doesn't allow me to output (for example) chinese or russian characters, or at least not easily.

Is it possible, on windows, to simulate a keyboard event by posting a WM_CHAR message ? That would be perfect if i could do it because i would simply have to retrieve the char code from a UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded configuration file, and post a message.

If it is possible, how can i do it on Windows CE and Windows Mobile ? I need to support both desktop and mobile devices.

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Does the manual help you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx *This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.*

Comment: Note: If you want to simulate a *keyboard*, you want to simulate *keypresses* (and releases), which requires you to send "Virtual Key Codes". Each *Virtual Key* directly corresponds to a key on your physical keyboard, *and NOT a specific character*. This is not the same as simulating *character input*, which would deal with `WM_CHAR`. The Virutal Key codes are translated into `WM_CHAR` messages by windows (`TranslateMessage`) according to the configured keyboard language and layout.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx

Comment: The `SendInput` function ta.speot.is mentions does allow specifying characters, look for `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`.

Comment: @dialer You mean that, if i use WM_CHAR, a text editor (for example) would receive that char, but would not trigger actions associated to that key ?

Comment: @Virus721 the (language-independent) virutal key codes, which for example come from the `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, are translated to `WM_CHAR` messages by Windows using the `TranslateMessage` function according to your keyboard language/layout settings. It depends on how the 'text editor' you mention is programmed, but for shortcuts, usually it checks whether for example the **virutal key** for CTRL is pressed, and then waits for the **WM_CHAR** message for `Z` (for example, "undo"). But in some applications (games mostly), the actual VK messages may be necessary.

Comment: @dialer Alright, so i guess there is not way to emit a (for example) russian keyboard event, from a non-russian keyboard ?

Comment: All keyboards use the same Virtual Key Codes. What character is associated with the key that was pressed can either be determined manually (program a lookup table from *Virtual Key Code* to the desired *character*), or (this is the normal solution), using the `TranslateMessage` function. This function translates for example a `WM_KEYDOWN` message for the Virtual Key `VK_S` to a `WM_CHAR` message for the Russian letter "C", if the keyboard layout in `intl.cpl` is Russian. (Because on a Russian keyboard, C is located where S would be on an US keyboard).

Comment: @dialer And is there a way to change the way windows translates VK to char code from within the program, without changing the OS language and keyboard related settings ? For example, if i'm compiling my program for russians but want to test it using my european keyboard, can i use something like TranslateMessageFromRussian() ?

Comment: That I don't know, but it may be possible. You can definitely change the keyboard settings with your program, but it would be permanent and system-wide. I'd suggest asking that as a new question on Stack Overflow. If it is not possible, you can leave out `TranslateMessage` and do it manually with a lookup table, but that would be a very tedious solution.

Comment: @Virus721 I don't understand why you would want that. If it's for testing, can't you just change the keyboard layout on your local system? There's no requirement that what you tell Windows the keyboard layout is, matches what it actually is.

Comment: @hvs Hmmm that's probably true.

Comment: @Virus721 I forgot about something: `TranslateMessage` is always in the *receiving* program (so, for example the text editor). You don't have any control whether or not `TranslateMessage` is called or not, so when you send Virtual Key Codes, most programs will inevitably translate them with `TranslateMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

Code demontrating how to simulate keyboard for unicode.
Beware:

1. you must activate the target application, since keyboard events are queued to the active app...
2. the target application must be unicode aware

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static void send_unicode( wchar_t ch ) {
    INPUT input;

    // init
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    input.ki.wVk = 0;
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    input.ki.wScan = ch;

    // down
    SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );

    // up
    input.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _tprintf( TEXT( "you have 5 seconds to switch to an application which accepts unicode input (as Word)...\n" ) );
    Sleep( 5000);
    _tprintf( TEXT( "Sending...\n" ) );
    send_unicode( 946 );   // lowercase greek beta
    send_unicode( 269 );   // lowercase c-hachek
    send_unicode( 12449 ); // japanese katakana small a
    send_unicode( 4595 );  // korean hangul jongseong phieuph-pieup

    return 0;

}
```